# sample code for change position of bitmap every milliseconds in android

Tags: android

I want to create a bitmap in wallpaper service is fine,but i want to change  bitmap position every 5milliseconds [lease help me `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y, null);any one`

Comment: Did you check the API Demos ?

Comment: i have taken x=rand.inextint()*widthofcanvas; y=rand.inextint()*heightofcanvas; afer 5milliseconds i want to cange x,y position

Comment: my wallpaper looks like a stars in sky

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps?

```
   while(true)
    {
    Thread.sleep(5);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y, null);
    }
```

Not sure though.

Comment: This is going to display bitmap for infinite time at same location, because you are not moving the x & y's value.